# Minecraft: I lost all my items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So a creeper blasted my chests and all of my items are on the ground and unfortunately, I did not have wood to make new chests so I left them on them on the ground to get wood. 34 jungle woods collected later, all of my items are gone. Including my armor and diamond sword. Do items disappear when they're not in a chest or my inventory?

Comment: I realise you're annoyed, but you should probably tone down your language a bit.

Comment: oh my bad, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

> Items despawn after 6000 game ticks (5 minutes) of being in a loaded
> chunk. [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_(entity))

Meaning if it took you more than 5 minutes to collect the wood, the dropped items are gone forever.

Comment: ahhh thanks! any chance I can find them again?

Comment: @esttlovee Sadly no ... despanw means they get destroyed ... I've lost many items deep in the caves being blown up by random creapers ..

Comment: If you want to prevent loosing dropped items in the future, here is a mod for you: https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/lingering-loot

Comment: If you prefer not to lose them but dont mind cheats on your world then i recommend /gamerule KeepInventory

Comment: @CaolanMC isn't that only to keep your inventory when you die?

Comment: didn't realiselise you meant that you don't want them to despawn instead of keeping them in your inventory.  Game files for decoding if you must (: